# Why use load() in jQuery instead of htmls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**update**: terribly sorry for not making myself clear. it is load() in jQuery, not loadpage().

maybe this is a trivial question but I just cannot think it through as new to js. I will really appreciate your help.

I am building a small personal site, containing several similar pages. Some tutorials I find suggest to use `load()` to, in one single .html file, based on different clicks, generate different content which is grabbed from my other html files using `load()`.

but why am I doing this? having several html files works fine. using `load()` method I still need those files; also I googled and see many complaints about the slow speed of `load()`.

therefore I am just wondering the reason we are doing this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `loadpage()`? It's not part of jQuery core.

Comment: JQ mobile has a loadpage method.

Comment: if you're using JQ mobile and your question is therefore "why use loadpage when I can have all the pages within the main html content?", then it's just a matter of trying to reduce time for initial load, and potentially bandwidth if you have pages that aren't accessed frequently.

Comment: sorry I misuse loadpage for load. fixed already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadpage()` is not a native jQuery method, so it's likely you've stumbled across an article that was providing some custom wrappers for jQuery's methods. On the other hand, `$.load()` is a native jQuery method that pulls remote content into your page asynchronously. Changes are good that if somebody constructed a `loadpage()` method, they may have in fact been using `$.load()` (or any one of the other [ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)) internally.

It's possible you're referring to [`$.mobile.loadPage`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html) (which uses jQuery's `$.ajax` beneath the covers), which is actually a jQuery Mobile method. You wouldn't be dealing with this too much unless you're involed in Mobile app development.

Whether you're using jQuery Mobile's `$.mobile.loadPage`, or jQuery's `$.load` to load in your content, the reason is still the same: avoid full page refreshes when partial page loading is all that's needed.

Think about what happens everytime you want to load a different HTML file. You have to reload the header, the navigation, the footer, sidebar information, graphics, and perhaps some media content, every time you load a new page - and a lot of this doesn't change from page to page. This is why it's helpful to be able to load in fragments of documents, without requiring the user to re-issue a request for everything all over again just to see the unique content on page 2.

Comment: $.load will still load the whole html, right? The technique will only work if page 2 and next are lightweight pages that don't include the header, navigation, etc.

Comment: @Christophe Not necessarily. You can pass in a selector to `$.load()` and pull in only a portion of the targeted document. For instance, `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');` would load the `#container` item from `test.html` and place it within the `#result` element of the current page.

Comment: Really? I would expect jQuery to still load the whole test.html, run the scripts if any, and only then extract #container. I don't see how ajax could only load a page fragment.

Comment: @Christophe Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, the full document is loaded, however it's not placed into the DOM, therefore the browser doesn't have to redraw large portions of the page. Of course many developers will serve up an ajax-version of their page when they detect an asynchronous request. They could send the unique data without the framing content.